# Android Density and ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin

ImageViews do not seem to scale but buttons do when I apply the following code

```
    var myDisplayMetrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    myDisplayMetrics.DensityDpi = DisplayMetricsDensity.Low;
    myDisplayMetrics.SetTo(myDisplayMetrics);
```

This came about because I noticed the ImageButtons were larger on the screen than the pixels size delivered. I investigated this and found a way to calculated the DP.

On hardware which gives DisplayMetrics as density=1.5, width=1920, height=1200, scaledDensity=1.83, xdpi=225.777, ydpi=225.77701 and this apparently gives a DP of 1280 x 800 hence the unexpected size

I applied the code above and the ImageButton appeared at the right size however the animation in the ImageView was still too big..

What is the standard way of fixing this? I am using Xamarin.

Comment: What is the problem in the first place? It is unclear from your question.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the delivered images in pixels do not appear as expected. I have a 1920x1200 screen but it appears as if it were a 1280x800. I am assuming the density is causing this.

Comment: can you share your code plz? that where you do your layout

Comment: I guess the problem can be summed up with, I have an image provided 300 x 171 for a screen that supports 1920 x 1200. When I render the ImageView it is much bigger than expected. I am assuming it is the density causing this issue and want to know how to turn it off.

e.g. myImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.TestImage);